Should I / how to retrieve miniconda installer SHA256 programatically?
I am setting up a Containerfile that should install miniconda.
The instructions for installing miniconda are available at: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html .
I am able to get the installer from https://docs.anaconda.com/miniconda/ as:
RUN wget --https-only https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b

However, one thing is missing here: checking the SHA256 hash of the .sh installer. I know where the SHA is (it is on https://docs.anaconda.com/miniconda/ ), however, I do not see a simple way to retrieve it programatically.

I could just "hard code" the hash value in my Dockerfile, but then the Dockerfile will break each time the installer gets updated, so I guess this is not a good idea?
To avoid this, I would like to get safely and programmatically the hash value through a RUN command in my Containerfile.

Any idea how I can do this?

Is it an option to select a specific version and not latest? That way the hash is fixed to the version you choose.

Yes, I have thought about that too. I would prefer to use latest for security reason, and I think I would prefer to use latest, and get a hard container build fault now and then and update the hash by hand, rather than silently used an outdated and vulnerable version.
